# Serial stops working shortly after startup

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

I'm using a Coral Dev Board Mini running Mendel Linux (a derivative of Debian) to run a python script on startup.

To test, I either add a crontab @reboot under the root user with `sudo crontab -e` or a systemctl service, that calls
`nohup script -c "sudo python3 main.py" -f log.txt`.

On the python script, I run

```py
from serial import Serial

serial = Serial("/dev/ttyS0", 1000000)
while True:
    try:
        serial.write(b"\x00")
        print("It worked")
    except:
        print("It didn't work :(")
```

If I check `log.txt`, I'll see that it worked for a while (~40 lines) before it stops working. If I remove the try except, I'll get

```
Thread-5:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 537, in write
    n = os.write(self.fd, d)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/mendel/.../main.py", line 110, in main
    serial.write(b"\x00")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 571, in write
    raise SerialException('write failed: {}'.format(e))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: write failed: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

I don't think it's a permissions issue? I checked with python ran with the same method and I had all the relevant permissions:

```py
print(os.access("/dev/ttyS0", os.R_OK))  # True
print(os.access("/dev/ttyS0", os.W_OK))  # True
print(os.access("/dev/ttyS0", os.X_OK))  # False
print(os.access("/dev/ttyS0", os.F_OK))  # True
```

```bash
$ ls -l /dev/ttyS0
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 64 Apr  7 19:28 /dev/ttyS0
```

Does anyone have any idea at all as to why my serial stops working a while after startup? I genuinely can't think of anything. I'd appreciate any help I can get.